# Some local fonts doesn't render on the browser

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I've created a small app to view all local fonts on a browser. [(Demo)](https://akinuri.github.io/local-fonts/).

I'm using Flash to get font names:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call("getFontList", getDeviceFonts());

function getDeviceFonts(): Array {
    var embeddedAndDeviceFonts: Array = Font.enumerateFonts(true);

    var deviceFontNames: Array = [];
    for each(var font: Font in embeddedAndDeviceFonts) {
        deviceFontNames.push(font.fontName);
    }
    deviceFontNames.sort();

    return deviceFontNames;
}
```

and later process the names and create a 4 column layout to view them:

```
function getFontList(fontList) {
    $("#flash").remove();

    fontList.forEach(function (fontName) {
        var cell = elem("div", {"class":"tile"}, [
                    elem("div", {"class":"fontName"}, fontName),
                    elem("div", {"class":"demo", "style":"font-family: \"" + fontName.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + "\", Consolas, Arial;"}),
                ]);
        output.append(cell);
    });

    updateCells($("#input").val());
}
```

This is working fine, but there's slight problem. Some fonts doesn't render on the browser, and the fallback font is applied.

For example, this font: `!PaulMaul`. I can view this on MS Word and Photoshop:

[image]

[image]

and this is how it looks (Consolas applied) on the browser:

[image]

I haven't encountered something like this before, so I don't know what the problem is. I thought any local font is usable on the browser, especially if MS Word and PS can render them fine. I guess, that isn't true.

What exactly is the problem here, and is there a way to solve this?

---

<sub>App is available on [Github](https://github.com/akinuri/local-fonts), if anyone wants to tinker.</sub>

Comment: I tested and noticed that the first font showed up in Chrome - but was not working, and it didn't show up in Edge (the extension was .fon), browsers don't support all font types, edge seems to filter those but Chrome doesn't.

Comment: just use a library to add the font so that they wont go away with no browser supports?